# Obtaining Current Build Number/Environment Settings in MTM Test Run

Tags: c#, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I have been trying to find a way to access the current Build Number and/or the current Environment Settings from MTM for a test suite run as part of a build. I wish to use this information within my own custom reports as the information provided by MTM does not capture everything I require.

Anyone been able to achieve this? I have read many posts of people trying, but they all seem to end at dead ends or Test Scribe, which just outputs the same data in a word doc and is fairly restricted (no custom filepath to save to, and is not run during tests).

Unfortunately I have no code to present what I have tried as I have not even been close. Though I have looked at TestContext in VisualStudio2010 quite closely and it does not appear to pick up much MTM info outside of the current TestCase being run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [TFS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx) for that.

We have implemented an external project (not as part of a team build) which is reporting the `TestResults` of a `TestRun` by passing as parameters the `TestRunId` or the `BuildNumber`. I think that if you use it as part of a build you will be able somehow to pass it as parameter on runtime or just get the latest Build.

You can check the following links for further details:

- [Get the Latest Build](http://www.woodwardweb.com/dotnet/tfs_build_api_b_1.html)
- [Get Build Definitions and Build Details](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/01/11/tfs-api-part-33-get-build-definitions-and-build-details.aspx)
- [Get Detailed Build Test Results](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/05/16/get-detailed-build-test-results-using-the-tfs-api.aspx)
- [Get Build Settings](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2012/05/23/tfs-api-part-46-vs11-team-settings.aspx)

Comment: This sounds very promising! Thank you, I shall look into it tomorrow when I have access to my machine and let you know how it goes.

Comment: You 're welcome. If any of the references will help you please post it  here.

Comment: I haven't used it yet, but I read through the links with code samples and it seems like the best way to go. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the following code to get the plan and build details through MTM

```
WorkItemStore workitemstore = tfsserv.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        Project tfsproject = workitemstore.Projects[tfsprojectname];
        ITestManagementService Mtmserveice = (ITestManagementService)tfsserv.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
        ITestManagementTeamProject mtmproj = Mtmserveice.GetTeamProject(tfsproject.Name);

        ITestPlan plan = mtmproj.TestPlans.Find(planid);
        Console.WriteLine("Test Plan: {0}", plan.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Plan ID: {0}", plan.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Build Currently In Use: {0}", plan.BuildNumber);
```